# Looping all elements in javascript to do parsing?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

So I'm trying to create something that emulates taglib (BodyTagSupport) JSP behaviour but into javascript, it's just to shrink code and make it a lot more understantable to the programmer.

So let's suppose:

```
<myTag id="x" class="someclass" myTagAttr="someAttr">
  <myTag id="y" class="someOtherclass" myTagAttr="someOtherAttr">
    <div>...</div>
  </myTag>
</myTag>
```

I want to loop and start checking myTag and it's attr, but I want to replace it totally, like let's say, the first iteration should render:

```
<div id="x" class="someclass">
  <otherTagMine>someAttr</otherTagMine>
  <myTag id="y" class="someOtherclass" myTagAttr="someOtherAttr">
    <div>...</div>
  </myTag>
</div>
```

Then it should check what is inside that tag

```
<div id="x" class="someclass">
  <button>someAttr</button>
  <div id="y" class="someOtherClass">
    <otherTagMine>someOtherAttr</otherTagMine>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then again inside each one

```
<div id="x" class="someclass">
  <button>someAttr</button>
  <div id="y" class="someOtherClass">
    <button>someOtherAttr</button>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the final code actually looks simplier, but it's just a example; it will perform annoying complex tasks, I'm good at java, BodyTagSupport does this in a very clean way, but it'd only be for JSP based server, and I'd like full support to any other server type, using just raw html and js, but never tried developing for javascript, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you open to using frameworks like jQuery or you want to do this with pure JavaScript? It's fairly trivial with jQuery.

Comment: Yes any framework to extend javascript is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AngularJS

My preferred method would be to use a directive with AngularJS. It allows you to define custom HTML tags and definitions for the browser on how to render them.

### Code

A sample JSFiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mw2P6/).

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<myTag id="x" class="someclass" myTagAttr="someAttr">
  <myTag id="y" class="someOtherclass" myTagAttr="someOtherAttr">
  </myTag>
</myTag>
</div>
```

#### Angular Code

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('mytag', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            var attr = $attr.mytagattr;
            $element.prepend('<button>' + attr + '</button>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Felishia Let me know if there's a particular framework you want this to work on and I'll see if I can get it working on that framework.

Comment: I'm actually open to any framework; I want to simplify as much as possible the bootstrap framework (even more than it already is) also add direct ajax support (which means jQuery), to help me pay for my education, maybe get donations or so.

Comment: I would recommend Angular then, because it should meet all your needs. There's a project called Bootstrap-UI which is a port of the Bootstrap framework to AngularJS. Angular also comes bundled with JLite (a lite version of JQuery), but you can run it with full jQuery if you need. Accept this answer if it meets your needs or expand your use case if you need me to modify my answer. Good luck!